# console.log a sequelize value in client.on() discord js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to **get** a **value** in the `client.on("ready")` but **if** i try to **console log** it I **get** **always** the **same value** even if it update. if I console log it in outside the `client.on("ready")` or inside `client.on("message")` (via chat command) i get the righ value.

I tried awaiting the `user.increment` but it doesn't work.

how can i fix it?

```
 const Tags = sequelize.define("leaderboard", {
      id: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        unique: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        defaultValue: null,
        allowNull: true,
      },
      messages_count: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        defaultValue: 0,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      rank: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        defaultValue: 1,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      time_rank: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        defaultValue: 0,
        allowNull: false,
      },
    }); 

    client.channels.map((x) => {
        if (x.type === "voice") {
          x.members.map(async (y) => {
            try {
              const addUser = await Tags.create({
                id: y.user.id,
                messages_count: 0,
                rank: 0,
              });
            } catch (e) {}
    

        
        const user = await Tags.findOne({
              where: { id: y.user.id },
            });        

              console.log("start");
              setInterval(function () {
                if (user) {
              // here the value is always the same for some reason
                  console.log(
                    "test",
                    user.get("rank"),
                  );
                  const isLevelUp = levelUp(y, user, user.get("rank"));
                  if (isLevelUp) {
                    message.channel.send(
                      `${y.user.name} has been levelled up to ${user.get("rank")}`
                    );
                  }
                  user.increment("rank");
                }
              }, millisPerHour); 
          });
        }
      });
    });
```